# CSS owerflow-auto on block inside block with max-height

Tags: css

I want to get next layout:

```
******
div with max-height 80% percents of a screen

------
div with fixed height
------
++++++
div which grows until parent div (marked with *) 
is smaller than it's max-height
After parent div have reached max-height, 
this div should show vertical scroll.  
++++++

******
```

I've created jsfiddle with example. You could uncomment `//max-height:210px;` in css to look what I want to achieve. But in fiddle I have predefined page size, and I could tune height of overflowed block. How could I do that in percents of page height?

http://jsfiddle.net/wxdtwq5x/6/

Comment: Is this what you're looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/fixit/wxdtwq5x/7/

Comment: No, I specify `.page` height in px just for fiddle, because jsfiddle uses frame to show result. Just Imagine, that `.page` div is a body. Div `.maxheight` is no higher than 80% of body. And I want to get scroll for div `.overflowed` which is inside `.maxheight` div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fixit/wxdtwq5x/10/

Comment: It's closer, but still not exactly what I want. In jsfiddle.net/fixit/wxdtwq5x/10 scrollbar applied to `.maxheight` div, so when you scroll "Static content" also moves. I want scrollbar applied to `.overflowed` div, so when you scroll, only "n bottles..." moves.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fixit/wxdtwq5x/11/

Comment: @YonatanAyalon you've made it. Thank you.